# How can I get $id variable in widget's form function?

Tags: functions, widgets, forms

How can I get $id variable in widget's form function?
According to widget's structure I see that widget function have $args as a parameter, which will be extracted in function's body. In my case i want to use $id variable (from extracted $args) which contains current sidebar's id. How can I make 'visible' $id variable  in form function? Any ideas?

```
class Ex_Widget_Example extends WP_Widget {
    //constructor goes here
    function widget($args, $instance) {extract($args);}
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance ) { }
    function form( $instance ) {}
}
```

For example we have sidebar with id 'my_sidebar'. I put this widget in it. For example my widget function, which we use to output something on page, looks like this:

```
function widget($args, $instance) {
         extract($args);
         echo $id; //or just echo $args['id'];
}
```

So on my page, in my 'my_sidebar' sidebar I will see a text 'my_sidebar'. That's great. But how can I get this $id or $args['id'] in widget's form function. In class example I see, that only widget function takes $args as argument. I'm not an expert in OOP pragramming, I tried to create a static variable (unsuccessfully), which would keep id value:

```
class Ex_Widget_Example extends WP_Widget {
    public static $widget_id;
    //constructor goes here
    function widget($args, $instance) {
             extract($args);
             self::$widget_id = $id;
             echo self::$widget_id //here outputs sidebar's id perfectly on my page
    }
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance ) { }
    function form( $instance ) {
             echo self::$widget_id //here outputs nothing on my widget's form
    }
}
```

Maybe wordpress call form function first, before widget function, that's why I can't see anything on my form ....anyway, any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Just to make that shure: You need the sidebar ID/Name - where the Widget was placed in - inside your widget?

Comment: Would you mind answering the question I asked ↑ here? Also: Please edit & improve your Q. So far there's a lot of confusion. :/

Comment: sorry, I'm a new guy here. 
Yes! I put this widget for example in 'my_sidebar'. In this widget's widget function I can just write something like: echo '$id'; and in my front-end I will see sidebar's id - 'my_sidebar'. but I need to use this $id variable in widget's form function, because I want to display in select box which widgets already have this 'my_sidebar'.

Answer (score 1):

Do you search for `$args['widget_id']`? Just save it in a variable you can access in `form()` later.

Look at `wp-includes/default-widgets.php` to see how widgets work. Not the best code, but it should give you some hints.

Comment: I know how to get widget id ....I don't know hot to 'transfer' this value in form function :(

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up on @toscho answer, you maybe could get the current sidebar (that holds the widget) via the DB options table:

```
$current_sidebar = array_search( 
    "{$this->id_base}-{$this->number}", 
    get_option( 'sidebars_widgets' ), 
    true 
);
```

*Not tested*

Comment: Can you explain exactly how to use this?

Comment: Inside your widget that's registered to a sidebar.

Comment: @user13250 any progress?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me inside the function for the form

```
public function form( $instance ) {
    $my_widget = $this;
    $widget_identifier = "{$this->id_base}-{$this->number}";
}
```

Edit: the following also works

```
public function form( $instance ) {
    $widget_identifier = $this->id;
}
```